# How do I remove the first five elements of an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, list

```
@array = qw(one two three four five six seven eight);
<Some command here>
print @array;
```

Comment: Perl's array handling is pretty deep. You don’t necessarily need to destroy the array to operate on it. This is just for example `print join("\n", @array[5..$#array]), $/;`

Comment: Too add to what Ashley said, I almost never find a need to remove elements from an array unless I'm using it as a stack. I would suspect you could improve your code so that the five elements aren't added to begin with (if they're unnecessary) or use an array slice as in Ashley's example to get at the elements you need without destroying the array.

Comment: One very simple question, 6 different working answers and counting. You just gotta love perl :)

Comment: @Cyber-Guard Design, hear hear!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Here are a few ways, in increasing order of dumbness:

Using a [slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices):

```
@array = @array[ 5 .. $#array ];
```

Using [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html):

```
splice @array, 0, 5;
```

Using [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html):

```
shift @array for 1..5;
```

Using [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
my $cnt = 0;
@array = grep { ++$cnt > 5 } @array;
```

Using [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html):

```
my $cnt = 0;
@array = map { ++$cnt < 5 ? ( ) : $_ } @array;
```

I'm sure far better hackers than I can come up with even dumber ways. :)

Comment: I do like the map solution, it's neat

Comment: i don't get how the map one works and i think i should ask a question on it.

Comment: Map will loop through `@array`, and assign the elements back to the array only after it has looped through first five. A ternary condition and `$cnt` variables are used to evaluate if we've loop through the five elements already.

Comment: i still don't get it:if $cnt less than 5 then list otherwise $_ = what?

Comment: `@b = map { $_, "\n"} @a` means: copy element in @a to $_, then add \n and then copy element in $_ to @b, so basically i understand the $_ bit, but the () bit doesn't make sense to me

Comment: why force `map` to be `grep`? `my $count = 0; my @new_array = grep {++$count > 5} @array;`

Comment: @friedo => If ordered by increasing dumbness, you have your first two examples transposed.  `splice` is the operation to do this, and does it efficiently. A self assigning array slice has to make a copy of every sliced element, and at worst requires `2*n` space to do so.  In fact, I'd probably place it below the repeated shift example.

Comment: @friedo, you can also use a `state` variable: `@array = grep { state $cnt; ++$cnt > 5 } @array;` no `my $cnt`, but you will have to `use feature 'state'` or `use 5.10.1` (I think thats the version)

Comment: can you explain why we have a `$#array` in the first method? That variable usage really confused me. What's going on, and why isnt the pound sign commenting out stuff?

Answer (score 14):

You are looking for the [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) builtin:

```
splice @array, 0, 5;
```

Answer (score 5):

`splice @array, 0, 5;` will do it.

Comment: splice is working only for numbers. not working for string elements inside array

Answer (score 4):

As a comment to friedo's answer and to demonstrate cool new declaration `state`, here it is using `grep`, which friedo's `map` emulates.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'state';

my @array = qw(one two three four five six seven eight);

my @new_array = grep {state $count; ++$count > 5} @array;

print "$_\n" for @new_array;
```

Answer (score -2):

I just realized you only need the last string, so no need to loop

```
   my $_ = "@array"; s|(?:.*?\s){5}||;say;
```

Btw this is probably the least efficient  way to do it, just having fun :)

Comment: to the downvoter: Although not exactly the 'best' way to do this, my code still works, and you should realize that I provided that answer only as another alternative to the 'more' correct solutions above.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess as to why is because this solution will break if any elements of `@array` contain spaces or if `$" ne ' '`.

Comment: Good find. I will try to figure that issue out